# PHP RecursiveDirectoryIterator list only files

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to make a code in PHP to list all files in directories and sub-directories in an array with their location, for this I'm using `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` class. But when I `print_r` my array, **here's the result**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SplFileInfo Object
        (
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => images\test\foo.png
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => foo.png
        )

    [1] => SplFileInfo Object
        (
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => images\testing2\testt.png
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => testt.png
        )

    [2] => SplFileInfo Object
        (
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => images\testing3\flowers.png
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => flowers.png
        )
)
```

**The result that i want:**

```
Array(
   images/test/foo.png
   images/testing2/testt.png
   images/testing3/flowers.png
)
```

**My code:**

```
    $imagesList = array();
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('images/')) as $filename) {
        if ($filename->isDir()) continue;
        $imagesList[] = $filename;
    }
    print_r($imagesList);
```

How can I do this ? Thanks

Comment: How about `$imagesList[] = $filename->getRealPath();` , if thast doesn't work look here [SplFileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) for the right method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to get only path to the file from RecursiveDirectoryIterator:

```
$imagesList = array();
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('images/')) as $filename) {
    if ($filename->isDir()) continue;
    $imagesList[] = str_replace("\\","/",$filename->getPathname());
}
print_r($imagesList);
```

Comment: Working but I get `images\test\foo.png` and not `images/test/foo.png`, how can I transform the backslash to a slash?

Comment: I don't want to get the real path, getPathName was good, just the backslash is the problem, I want to transform it to a slash, so how can I do it ? Beacause realPath give me C:\xampp\htdocs ect

Comment: got it. Check the final solution